# C# - "print spooler" service for non admin users

Tags: c#

I dont know c# but im trying to create winforms app (windows 10) that can change the privileges of the service "print spooler" so it be able to do stop and start to the service without admin user.
What i mean is that i want to make a button that put a specific user that i want and he will be able to start/stop the service and he wont be administrator.
**I dont really need c# any kind of computer language is welcome**

I tried new process but it didnt work will

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/grant-users-rights-manage-services#method-3-use-subinaclexe

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to write a code that restart a service with admin privileges, but i have a user that have regular privilege